# Ожидание инициализации всех контролов в новой форме

Tags: c++, c++builder, form

Есть две формы. По нажатию кнопки в первой, отображается вторая форма внутри первой, но из-за того, что на ней много контролов, она долго инициализируется (мерцает). Как мне сделать ожидание до полной инициализации контролов на форме?

Comment: ничего непонятно